# Image analysis through GLCM Matrix

Tags: image, image-processing, glcm

I have a image for which I have to calculate the GLCM texture of a selected region. How can I calculate this? I have to calculate the GLCM only for gray area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a Grey-Level Co-occurrence Matrix you simply count how often certain grey Values are Neighbours.

An Example:

```
Image
1 1 0 2 
1 2 2 2
2 2 1 0
```

Now we define our GLCM as:

```
GLCM
     0     1     2
   ------------------
0 | (0,0) (0,1) (0,2)
  |
1 | (1,0) (1,1) (1,2)
  |
2 | (2,0) (2,1) (2,2)
```

Where `(x,y)` denotes that how often is the Value `y` right of the Value `x`

For our Example we get:

```
GLCM
    0     1     2
   ------------------
0 | 0     0     1
  |
1 | 2     1     1
  |
2 | 0     1     3
```

You can extend this to get more than only the next neighbour or adjust the direction (North, East, South-East etc.) you look for a neighbour if this gives any benefits to your application. You can even create GLCM for every Pixel direction.

After that you can achieve a symmetricall GLCM by counting again but interchanging the position of `x` and `y` to get `(y,x)`.

After you have a symmetrical GLCM you can normalize it to get your GLCM Texture.

There is an excellent Paper from Haralick et.al. that you can read: [Textural Features for Image Classification](http://www.makseq.com/materials/lib/Articles-Books/Filters/Texture/Co-occurence/haralick73.pdf).